# PKCS Luna Support in new AWS Cloud HSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, pkcs#11, hsm

We are planning to migrate from Classic HSM to New Cloud HSM offered by AWS. Does the New HSM also Support PKCS#11 luna libraries. What are the alternatives possible if it doesn't ?

Comment: Can you offer some link/doc about PKCS#11 Luna Library? Application should work with New CloudHSM as PKCS#11 is a standard.

Comment: http://cloudhsm-safenet-docs-5.4.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Content/Home_sa.htm

http://cloudhsm-safenet-docs-5.4.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Content/sdk/pkcs11/pkcs11_standard.htm

http://cloudhsm-safenet-docs-5.4.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Content/sdk/extensions/safenet_extensions.htm

https://cloudhsm-safenet-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/007-011136-002_lunasa_5-1_webhelp_rev-a/Content/sdk/s1_-_general.htm

Comment: AWS SD guide quote : "The major API provided with Luna Product Software Development Kit conforms to RSA Laboratories' Public-Key Cryptography Standards #11 (PKCS #11) v2.20. A set of API services (called PKCS #11 Extensions) designed by SafeNet, augments the services provided by PKCS#11. The API is a library – a DLL in Windows, a shared object in Solaris, AIX and Linux, a shared library in HP-UX – called Chrystoki".

My query : Are these major APIs as well as extensions still supported in new generation Cloud HSm provided by AWS.